# Running Program from USB drive

Tags: c#, winforms, portability

I have a C# winForms program that is designed to run off a USB drive from multiple PCs. When I connect the USB drive to another PC, the drive letter change. How can I make my drive letter consistent across all PCs, or make my program truly "portable". I need the drive letter because I have a SQLite Database datasource pointed to a certain directory. And i also have PDF files opening from a certain directory with a specific drive letter. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the drive letter in the first place?

Comment: you can try letters for usb drive with try-catch. your file path in the usb drive doesn't change. it will eventually catch the right condition.

Comment: I need the drive letter because I have a SQLite Database datasource pointed to a certain directory. And i also have PDF files opening from a certain directory with a specific drive letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the executing assembly path.

```
string path = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
```

From there, you can obtain the drive letter (path root):

```
string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
```

If your file is in the same directory as the executable, you can get the file path like this:

```
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName((new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath);
string databaseFile = Path.Combine(directory, "filename.dbf");
```

Comment: Ahh.. @PatrickHofman ... again. Care to enlighten us as to what the issue is with this answer?

Comment: OP wants to know how to fix the drive letter. The answer given is 'this is how to get the executable path'. They are not related.

Comment: @Benjamin the issue is that we can guess, but that it's entirely unclear what OP is asking. If it is _"How can I get the directory that my executable is in?"_, then that is a duplicate which has been answered tens of times on the site and should not be answered but flagged as such instead.

Comment: I am answering this question: "How can I make my drive letter consistent across all PCs, or make my program truly "portable".", or rather my interpretation of this question.

Comment: No... he says "OR.. make the program truly portable"... As this removes the need for hard coded drive paths... Its a valid answer.

Comment: Basically this is the answer that the OP needs, not what he asked.

Comment: Then explain the relation between the assembly path and the need to get the drive letter. Currently it doesn't say anything.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the relevant code to obtain the drive letter.

Comment: @MichaelG: I updated your answer a little to get the directory and point to the correct file.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Thank you, this is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the directory of your application.

```
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

(if you call `SetCurrentDirectory()`, use this: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(new System.Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);`)

Do you want your drive? (Drive's always 1 letter)

```
path.Substring(0, 2);
```

If not one letter,

```
path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Comment: You have to be careful using this, because someone can call SetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: I need the drive letter because I have a SQLite Database datasource pointed to a certain directory. And i also have PDF files opening from a certain directory with a specific drive letter.

Comment: @ehuizar Well here you go.